# Unable to pass a view function with two arguments in Django resulting in No Reverse Match Error

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

I am unable to understand why am I getting this error. If someone can please explain me why and how I can fix it, I am hoping that it will correct the underlying misconceptions that I probably have about `Django` `views` and `urls`.

```py
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'download' with keyword arguments '{'name': 'Dr. XYZ', 'date': '14 July 2020'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['download/$']
```

I have a function called `download` in my `views.py` which takes two arguments: `name` and `date`

**Views.py**

```py
def download (request, name, date):
    x = date.split(" ")
    date = f"29 {x[3]} {x[4]}"
    image = Image.open("certificates\static\certificates\Certificate_0001.jpg")
    font_type = ImageFont.truetype('arial.ttf', 70)
    font_type_2 = ImageFont.truetype('arial.ttf', 35)
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
    draw.text(xy=(810, 740), text=name, fill=(0,102,0), font=font_type)
    draw.text (xy=(330, 1230), text=date, fill=(0,102,0), font=font_type_2)
    image.save(f"certificates\static\certificates\{name}.pdf", "PDF", resolution=100.0)
    return HttpResponse ("works")
```

I am calling this function upon a link click in my `html` file.

```html
 <a class="nav-link active" href="{% url 'certificates:download' name=name date=program %}" download>Download Certificate</a>
```

The url configuration is:

**urls.py**

```py
from django.urls import path

from . import views

app_name = "certificates"
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"), 
    path("download", views.download, name="download")

]
```

It is confirmed that there is no syntax or other logical error in my function. If I remove the two arguments in my `html` file then there is no error i.e. if I say `html href="{% url 'certificates:download' %}` . However, if I bring the two arguments `name` and `date` I get this `NoReverseMatch` error.

Please explain what is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Link you have in <a ... > tag goes to 'certificates/download/somename/somedate'. i.e you passing arguments 'somename' and 'somedate'
So you should add that parametres in your url configurations

```
path("download/<str:name>/<str:date>", views.download, name="download")
```

And then you taking that parametres in your view function
`def download (request, name, date):`

let me know if it worked

Comment: worked! Thank you so much! May I please ask why Django needs us to specify this?

Comment: To put it simply Django needs to capture values from url. So you need to specify that they exist. You find some useful info in [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the function parameters in your URL definition as such

```
path("download/<str:name>/<str:date>", name="download")
```

That way the reverse function can resolve your function with the correct parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add these arguments to your `urls.py` file as well, i.e.:

```
path("download/<str:name>/<str:date>/", views.download, name="download"),
```

However, I'm not sure about the formatting of your date, so you might need to change that part a bit.